# MigraDoc : big table divided into 2 parts in one page

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation, migradoc

I am working on creating a report with MigraDoc that would be able to have table with 2 columns divided in the same page. It's possible with any settings of Table object?
[Draft image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9guR3.png)

Answer (score 0):

MigraDoc cannot do that on its own.

You can get a PDF with such a table if you create a MigraDoc document with just 50% page width (and the height of your page body) and then use PDFsharp to draw two pages from the MigraDoc document onto one page of the final PDF.

This sample draws 9 large pages as thumbnails on one page and cane be used to get started:
http://pdfsharp.net/wiki/MixMigraDocAndPdfSharp-sample.ashx